# How can I set a default value for Flexdatalist using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using Flexdatalist to provide auto completion functionality.
My script is something like the following:

```
$('#locationKeyword').flexdatalist({
        url: 'serverAction',
        cache: false,
        searchIn: ["ProvinceName", "CityName", "TownName"],
        visibleProperties: ["ProvinceName", "CityName", "TownName"],
        groupBy: 'ProvinceName',
        value:'1,1,1',
        selectionRequired: false,
        focusFirstResult: true,
        minLength: 1,
        maxShownResults: 20,
        valueProperty: '{Value}',
        textProperty: '{ProvinceName}, {CityName}, {TownName}',
        searchContain: true
    });
```

The server side code(Asp.NET MVC) returns an array of objects like the following:

```
return Json(new
        {
            ProvinceName = item.Province.Name,
            CityName = item.City.Name,
            TownName = item.Town.Name,
            Value = item.ProvinceId + "," + item.CityId + "," + item.TownId
        });
```

All item.ProvinceId, item.CityId, item.TownId are int;

The problem:
How can I set a default value for it. For example, I want to one combination of Province,City,Town to be selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all!

I found the solution as below:

Html:

```
<input name="BusinessLocation" type="text" class="locationKeyword" />
```

Script:

```
$('[name=BusinessLocation]').flexdatalist({
        url: options.businessLocationUrl,
        cache: false,
        searchIn: ["ProvinceName", "CityName", "TownName"],
        visibleProperties: ["ProvinceName", "CityName", "TownName"],
        groupBy: 'ProvinceName',
        selectionRequired: true,
        focusFirstResult: true,
        minLength: 1,
        maxShownResults: 20,
        textProperty: '{ProvinceName}, {CityName}, {TownName}',
        searchContain: true,
        valueProperty: 'Value'
    });        

    $('.locationKeyword').each(function (index) {
        if ($(this).hasClass('flexdatalist-alias')) {
            $(this).val('تهران, تهران, یوسف آباد');
        } else {
            $(this).val('1,1,1');
        }
    });

    $('[name=BusinessLocation]').val('1,1,1');
```

Comment: I am also trying to pre-populate multiple values from the url but this solution that you provided didn't seem to work. The documentation shows the example but that is if the data is from a json file. Can you please suggest how I can do so.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and I could solve it as follows.

for set a single value you could use,

```
$('.flexdatalist').flexdatalist('value', 'tagName1');
```

for set multiple values you could use,

```
var tagArray = ['1','7','10','11']; //tag ids in an array (you can use your own array here)
            
$('.flexdatalist').val(tagArray.toString());
$('.flexdatalist').flexdatalist({
  minLength: 1,
  searchIn: 'tagName',
  valueProperty: 'tagId',
  data: 'yourJsonFile',
  limitOfValues: 5 //multiple select maximum 5
});
```